# MySQL - How to unpivot columns to rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, union, unpivot, lateral-join

```
ID | a  | b  | c 
1  | a1 | b1 | c1
2  | a2 | b2 | c2
```

How do I reorganize the rows as `ID`, `columntitle`, `value`?

```
1 | a1 | a
1 | b1 | b
1 | c1 | c
2 | a2 | a
2 | b2 | b
2 | c2 | c
```

Comment: are you mean 'ID,value,columntitle' ?

Comment: Yes, but the order doesn't matter so much, as long as the rows are ID - column title - value

Answer (score 30):

You are trying to *unpivot* the data. MySQL does not have an unpivot function, so you will have to use a `UNION ALL` query to convert the columns into rows:

```
select id, 'a' col, a value
from yourtable
union all
select id, 'b' col, b value
from yourtable
union all
select id, 'c' col, c value
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b424e/1).

This can also be done using a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select t.id,
  c.col,
  case c.col
    when 'a' then a
    when 'b' then b
    when 'c' then c
  end as data
from yourtable t
cross join
(
  select 'a' as col
  union all select 'b'
  union all select 'c'
) c
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b424e/5)

Answer (score 8):

It took a long time coming, but MySQL version 8.0.14 finally added support for lateral joins - the official terminology is [lateral derived tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html).

This is a very powerful feature, that comes handy in multiple situations, including unpivoting table columns to rows.

You can phrase the query as follows:

```
select t.id, x.*
from mytable t
cross join lateral (
    select a, 'a' 
    union all select b, 'b'
    union all select c, 'c'
) as x(col1, col2)
```

It may look like this is not a big difference compared to the typical cannonical solution - after all, we are still using `union all` within the lateral derived table... But don't get it wrong: this query *scans the table only once*, as opposed to the other approach, which requires one scan for each column to unpivot. So this is more efficient - and the performance gain increases dramatically as the table goes bigger and/or more columns need to be unpivoted.

Bottom line: if you are running MySQL 8.0.14 or higher, just use this technique. From that version onwards, this is the canonical way to unpivot in MYSQL.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nXUO5Upi)**:

Sample data:

```
ID | a  | b  | c 
-: | :- | :- | :-
 1 | a1 | b1 | c1
 2 | a2 | b2 | c2
```

Query results:

```
id | col1 | col2
-: | :--- | :---
 1 | a1   | a   
 1 | b1   | b   
 1 | c1   | c   
 2 | a2   | a   
 2 | b2   | b   
 2 | c2   | c
```

---

**Update**

MySQL 8.0.19 first introduced support for [the `VALUES` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html), which could help further shortening the query by removing the need to use `union all` in a subquery (although I don't see any performance gain here, this makes the query neater). As of version 8.0.30, we can express the lateral join like so:

```
select t.id, x.*
from mytable t
cross join lateral (values 
    row(a, 'a'), 
    row(b, 'b'),
    row(c, 'c')
) as x(col1, col2);
```

Comment: There appears to be [a bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109252) when using values statement with lateral derived tables. The values statement is only outputting data for the first row of the outer table.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [UNION ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).

```
SELECT ID, a, 'a' 
FROM tbl
WHERE ID = 1
UNION
SELECT ID, b, 'b' 
FROM tbl
WHERE ID = 2
```

Comment: Get rid of the `WHERE` clauses. Otherwise you're only showing one column for each ID, instead of all columns for each ID.