# MySQL first select column based on parameter value and then value of column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table lets say

**Table1**

```
t_id A   B  C

100  1   1  0

101  1   0  1

102  1   1  0
```

Now I have input parameter param0 based on which first I have to select column (lets say B) and then using t_id value(lets say 101) i will be selecting value of that selected column(which is 0).

I want to create single query as i will be using it in join query.

Is above possible, if yes how to write the sql for same?

Comment: `select B from table1 where t_id = 101`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, this is most easily done with a `case` statement:

```
select (case when @param0 = 'A' then A
             when @param0 = 'B' then B
             when @param0 = 'C' then C
        end) as val
from table t
where id = @t_id;
```

Actually, it is most easily done with a case statement in almost any database.

Answer (score 2):

This is valid for SQL server. I am not sure if this will work in mySQL
You can do this easily by unpivoting the data and then selecting column and tid using parameters in `where` clause
For MySql you should probably look into [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184381/mysql-turn-table-into-different-table) on stackoverflow

```
SELECT Colvalue FROM (
SELECT t_id, ColName, ColValue
FROM 
   (SELECT t_id,A,B,C FROM tablename) t
UNPIVOT
   (Colvalue FOR ColName IN  (A,B,C) )AS unpvtt) 
WHERE t_id=@paramTid AND Colname=@paramColname
```