# MySQL Select multiple column depending on column value

Tags: mysql, if-statement, select, case

I searched the Internet and whole Stackoverlow twice, but didn't find a working solution.

Say I have a Table with following Columns:
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i

a is an integer which goes from 1-16
Depending on this value i have to choose if i select b-i.

Example: 
if a = 1 I need b,c,d,e,i. if a = 2 I need e,g,h,i

So I could use:

```
SELECT
CASE a WHEN 1 THEN b WHEN 2 THEN NULL ELSE NULL END as a
....
CASE a WHEN 1 THEN NULL WHEN 2 THEN g ELSE NULL END as g
```

Isn't there an easier way like:

```
CASE a When 1 (select b,c,d,e,i)?
```

Bonus wish: Can I select as depending on value of a? Example

```
if a = 1 column b should be named "lol", if a = 2 b should be called "rofl".
```

Comment: You can't return a different number of columns for different rows in the result.

Comment: @Barmar Well you can unpivot and dinamic pivot again. but is messy.

Comment: This kind of problem is highly symptomatic of poor design.

Comment: Check this one, to see how unpivot your table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184381/mysql-turn-table-into-different-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can think of to what you want would be to concatenate the columns you want:

```
SELECT CASE a
           WHEN 1 THEN CONCAT_WS(', ', b, c, d, e, i)
           WHEN 2 THEN CONCAT_WS(', ', e, g, h, i)
       END AS result
```

Another solution is to use `UNION`

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, e, i
FROM yourTable
WHERE a = 1
UNION
SELECT a, e, g, h, i, null
FROM yourTable
WHERE a = 2
```

Note that you can't have different column aliases depending on the value of `a`. There's just one set of column names for the entire query. In a `UNION`, they come from the column names or aliases in the first subquery.

Comment: True. If you want to put something in its place, use `IFNULL(e, 'something')`

Comment: I think this solution isn't my favorite. I need to work with those column in php, so exploding and renaming them isn't beautiful :( Hopefully someone got another idea...

Comment: I've added another solution using `UNION`.

Comment: Why don't you just return all the columns, and then distinguish between the cases in PHP?

Comment: I'm thinking of performance... Is there a noticeable difference in selecting 50 columns (20 of them null) and working with them in php or selecting 20 with mysql doing the work?

Comment: It depends on how big the data in those columns is, how many rows you're selecting, and the speed of the connection between the application and database (are they on the same machine or connected via a network?).

Comment: General recommendation: first implement the simple design. If performance is a problem, then worry about optimizing it.

Comment: approx max 30 rows, mainly numerals with max 10 length and some varchar(100). I would do the select and sorting in php on the same machine.

Comment: A silk purse from a pig's ear

Comment: Or, return all of the columns, but just replace the value with NULL when it's not needed...  `SELECT a, IF(a IN (1,2,5,7),b,NULL) AS b, IF(a IN (2,3,6,8),c,NULL) AS c, `

Comment: @chack For such a small query, performance differences should be negligible. Don't even start to worry about performance until you get into the thousands.

Comment: alright, thanks everyone! Will doing the work with php :)