# How to Unpivot a table in phpMyAdmin that have 200 columns and 250 rows without hardcoding it?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, unpivot

Actual table is in form of:

```
ID | a  | b  | c 
1  | a1 | b1 | c1
2  | a2 | b2 | c2
```

and expecting table to be:

```
1 | a | a1
1 | b | b1
1 | c | c1
2 | a | a2
2 | b | b2
2 | c | c2
```

How can I write effectively for 200 column table without hard coding it?

Comment: There's a similar question "MySQL - turn table into different table": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184381/mysql-turn-table-into-different-table