# Import csv into mysql where multiple columns needs to be multiple rows

Tags: mysql, csv

From a client I got the following csv file:

```
font_id, fontstyle1, fontstyle2, fontstyle3
1,2,7
2,3,8
3,1
4,8,7,9
```

So there is 1 font per row, and each font can belong to multiple font styles.
In the DB it will be multiple rows per font. So for instance font 1 will be:

```
font_id | font_style
1       | 2
1       | 7
2       | 3
2       | 8
3       | 1
4       | 8
4       | 7
4       | 9
```

So each font has a variable amount of font styles (so a variable amount of rows in the csv.

I have been looking but cant think of the right search phrase to find a solution. Could anyone point me in the right direction

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: unpivot columns

Comment: You just need a bit of application code to parse the file. Does the order in which styles appear carry any innate meaning?

Comment: @Strawberry no it doesnt have any meaning. Normally I would write some script in python that would import this data. Just curious if mysql itself could do something like this

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Thanks for the hint! I found a question that can point me in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184381/mysql-turn-table-into-different-table and started a vote to close the question