# mysql show column based on value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an unusual table structure which looks like this:

```
fruit   january   february   march
----------------------------------
apple   10        9          3
banana  2         1          1
grape   8         7          7
```

What type of select given 'apple' as the value of the row in the fruit column will give me the column and the highest number for that column, ie

apple, january, 10

Comment: You need to unpivot your data, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184381/mysql-turn-table-into-different-table

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, not to be nasty but the question should be improved a little, the title is much too generic IMO, you want to do more than just add a `where` clause, also, there are not really different "types" of select requests

Comment: Stop with all this silliness, and just have a usual table structure instead.

Comment: @ Strawberry - I agree, a bit awk-ing would do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *unusual table structure* allows complicated and not so elegant solutions.
You can use the function [`greatest()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) to get the max value for `'apple'` and use it in a `CASE` statement to get the month's name:

```
select
  fruit,
  case greatest(january, february, march)
    when january then 'january'
    when february then 'february'
    when march then 'march'
  end,
  greatest(january, february, march)
from tablename
where fruit = 'apple'
```

I hope you understand what you have to do if the table contains 12 columns for the 12 months.

Comment: Would this work consistently where greatest value appears in two months?

Comment: No, it will return the 1st month with that greatest value.