# SQL QUERY - ROWS TO COLUMN AND UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

[image]

Hello everyone,

1/ I want to do a sql query that transform the result from row to column like it's shown in the picture. Is it possible ?

2/ How can I update the second table with the first one ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - turn table into different table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184381/mysql-turn-table-into-different-table)

Comment: if you have a static column count see the duplicate, if the count is dynamic you have to use INFORMATION SCHEMA.columns for that and program it

Comment: Just rotate your monitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use  in the query

```
select 'EH545WL' as name, EH545WL as value from car union select 'FJ281TJ' as name, FJ281TJ as value from car;
```

If you use this query, you could get the result you want.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that you can transform this data.

**Create Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable([EH545WL] varchar(10), [FJ281TJ] varchar(10));

INSERT INTO yourTable
VALUES
    (0,0);
```

**Unpivot table:**

```
SELECT ID,Value
FROM yourTable
UNPIVOT (value for ID in ([EH545WL],[FJ281TJ])) up
```

Comment: Okay thank you very much ! One more question is that how can I update the second table with the first one ?

Comment: @JulieTarnaud One thing you can do is after you get the desired output, drop the first table. Also please upvote/accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: I don't see your point. Because I need first table to update the second but I don't know how to realize the update

Comment: @JulieTarnaud Please see the updated sql code that lets you create table and update the same table in unpivot mode.