# distinct of multiple columns snowflake

Tags: mysql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, distinct

I have a table called `XYZ` having 3 columns `adb1, adb2, adb3`.(All columns are of number type)

I want a query to return a distinct number from all these 3 columns as a single row.

For example:- Table **XYZ**

| adb1 | adb2 | adb3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 12 | 13 |
| 12 | 24 | 25 |
| 78 | 25 | 13 |

Now the query should return one single column having distinct values from all these columns i.e.

| Result column |
| --- |
| 11 |
| 12 |
| 13 |
| 24 |
| 25 |
| 78 |

Comment: first unpivot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184381/mysql-how-to-unpivot-columns-to-rows then distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative using `flatten`. The idea is to create an array using your columns and then flatten them up in multiple rows

```
select distinct t2.value::integer as new_col --cast it to appropriate data type
from your_table t1, 
     lateral flatten(input=>[t1.adb1,t1.adb2,t1.adb3]) t2
```

Answer (score 0):

UNION should achieve this but can be computationally expensive depending on how many you are performing and the amount of data it needs to de-dupe

Something like:

```
SELECT adb1 FROM xyz
UNION
SELECT adb2 FROM xyz
UNION
SELECT adb3 FROM xyz
```