# Columns To Rows with Condition from single table on MariaDB Server

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, relationship

I have table on like this :

```
id_biling  | disc_A  | disc_B | disc_C
    1         100        0        0
    2         200       300      400
    3         500        0       600
```

I want to get result like this :

```
id_biling  | disc |  Desc
    1        100     Disc_A
    2        200     Disc_A 
    2        300     Disc_B
    2        400     Disc_C
    3        500     Disc_A
    3        600     Disc_C
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - How to unpivot columns to rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184381/mysql-how-to-unpivot-columns-to-rows)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (You've already got one product specific answer, don't waste other people's time writing answers for 'wrong' dbms.)

Comment: sorry , i forget about dbms, i using mariadb server 10.7.5

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with *SQL server*

You can use [unpivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16).

```
select *
from   t
UNPIVOT  
   (disc FOR "DESC" IN   
      (disc_A, disc_B, disc_C)  
)AS unpvt;
```

| id_biling | disc | DESC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | disc_A |
| 2 | 200 | disc_A |
| 2 | 300 | disc_B |
| 2 | 400 | disc_C |
| 3 | 500 | disc_A |
| 3 | 600 | disc_C |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3p3gVYof?hide=4)

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved inspirated by [MySQL - How to unpivot columns to rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184381/mysql-how-to-unpivot-columns-to-rows)

```
(select id_billing, 'DISC_A' DESCR, DISC_A as DISC from tTable where DISC_A > 0 ) 
union all 
(select id_billing, 'DISC_B' DESCR, DISC_B as DISC from tTable where DISC_B > 0 ) 
union all 
(select id_billing, 'DISC_C' DESCR, DISC_C as DISC from tTable where DISC_C > 0 ) 
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).