# MySQL: Unpivot specific columns into 2 output columns

Tags: sql, mysql, union, unpivot

I have the following table:

| id | start_1 | start_2 | end_1 | end_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | day | night | night | day |
| 2 | night | night | day | night |

How can I UNPIVOT to get some of the values in one column, and some in another?

Like this:

| id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | day | night |
| 1 | night | night |
| 2 | night | day |
| 2 | night | night |

I found solutions to return all the values in one column, but I'm unable to convert it to two columns.

```sql
select t.id,
  s.start_orig,
  case s.start_orig
    when 'start_1' then start_1
    when 'start_2' then start_2
  end as start,
   e.end_orig,
  case e.end_orig
    when 'end_1' then end_1
    when 'end_2' then end_2
  end as end
from table t
cross join
(
  select 'start_1' as start_orig
  union all select 'start_2'
) s
cross join
(
  select 'end_1' as end_orig
  union all select 'end_2'
) e
```

*query from: [MySQL - How to unpivot columns to rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184381/mysql-how-to-unpivot-columns-to-rows)*

But then I get start_n * end_n rows, which is too many

| id | start_orig | start | end_orig | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | start_1 | day | end_1 | night |
| 1 | start_1 | night | end_2 | night |
| 1 | start_2 | night | end_1 | day |
| 1 | start_2 | night | end_2 | night |
| 2 | start_1 | day | end_1 | night |
| 2 | start_1 | night | end_2 | night |
| 2 | start_2 | night | end_1 | day |
| 2 | start_2 | night | end_2 | night |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only one `CROSS JOIN` can do the job :

```
  with cte as (
  select t.id, s.start_orig,
    case s.start_orig
      when 'start_1' then start_1
      when 'start_2' then start_2
    end as start, s.end_orig,
    case s.end_orig
      when 'end_1' then end_1
      when 'end_2' then end_2
    end as end
  from mytable t
  cross join (
    select 'start_1' as start_orig, 'end_1' as end_orig
    union all select 'start_2', 'end_2'
  ) s
  order by id
)
select id, start, end
from cte;
```

[Demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8LtVdxjtT96Km8XeaXvPeZ/0)