# Turn column names to values

Tags: sql, mysql, data-ingestion

I have a table like this:

| Datetime | Milan | London |
| --- | --- | --- |
| YY/MM/DD | 302 | 267 |
| YY/MM/DD | 54 | 108 |

and I'm trying to alter the table to have the column names as values in a column named "city" and the values in the cities column in a new column named "wind_direction"

| Datetime | City | wind _direction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| YY/MM/DD | Milan | 302 |
| YY/MM/DD | Milan | 54 |
| YY/MM/DD | London | 267 |
| YY/MM/DD | London | 108 |

I tried looking in ALTER TABLE syntax but nothing helped me

Comment: Some good examples here (I answered, but I will delete as the answers at this link do a better job of explaining and giving options)? [MySQL - How to unpivot columns to rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184381/mysql-how-to-unpivot-columns-to-rows)

Comment: Another idea might be to use concat and look up the information schema so that you can use that to loop through all the dynamic column names to then feed that into your insert statement for each row.  But JNevill's recommendation is best since it seems a built in system like this exists already.

Comment: agreed although it is nice to also see that the table has many columns but the typed version is still superior

Comment: I used the union all and it worked, thank you very much guys.